# Monitoring JDBC connection pools

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm connecting my Java application via JDBC driver and Tomcat configurations. I used [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html/) class to define my configurations. But sometimes, I got following exceptions:

- `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLTimeoutException`: Statement cancelled due to timeout or client request
- `java.sql.SQLException`: Query execution was interrupted
- `java.sql.BatchUpdateException`: Statement cancelled due to timeout or client request

But there is not much load on database, so I think the problem is about my configuration. Here are some of my configs:

- maxActive = 100
- minIdle = 10
- initialSize = 10
- maxWait =  10000
- maxIdle = 15

These are for some heavily loaded system. So I need to observe if my pool size is enough and other things like available connection count at any time. Is there any nice way of monitoring inside of connection pools?

Answer (score 1):

For the timeout exceptions, consider the following pseudocode:

```
if(!connection.isValid())
  connection = getNewConnection();
resultSet rs = connection.execute(qry);
```

Basically check if your connection has timed out before you execute the query.

If your query was interrupted, theres not much you can do other than to rollback the transaction and try again.

Comment: Is it possible a connection is timed out before I get it from connection pool?

Comment: I believe it is possible yes.  If you are using the c3p0 connection pool, you can use the properties idleConnectionTestPeriod and preferredTestQuery to ensure that your connections are always active.

Answer (score 0):

Enable JMX and tomcat will register your datasources with it's mbean server. You can then use jconsole to look at the connection pool details.

Comment: I don't use Tomcat actually, just configuration is made on Tomcat classes. Because there is no tomcat folder, I couldn't enable jmx on tomcat. Is this still valid then?

Comment: Also, my application is in a remote Linux server and jconsole cannot connect to non-JRMP servers apparently.